# Using SharePoint to access and modify data in database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have a situation where I currently have a huge spreadsheet that is used for tracking 40+ deliverables for projects. The spreadsheet solution is past cumbersome.

I have been thinking about how I can use our SharePoint instance to handle some of these tasks. One option that I have been thinking about was to create a relational database (MSSQL) and then use SharePoint to access and modify the data. I would like to be able to grant users access to specific data elements to allow users to modify the data rather on depending on an administrative resource. This will require some development.

I am relatively new to working with SharePoint so there must be some better ways to implement this functionality rather than the typical list functionality. Right now I am looking for some ideas and this is the best place to find them.

Thank you in advance. Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not fond of sharepoint, what I am fond of is developing external applications and framing that application within sharepoint.  That is my recommendations.  Write the application in vb.net / C# as a web application and use the page viewer web part to embed that application into the portal.

This avoids having to understand the sharepoint model, it keeps your concentration on more important things like databases, c# code, object oriented programming, etc.

No offense to the sharepoint developers of course.

Comment: None taken! :) This is how we develop most of our modules which require more .net development. Another advantage is we were able to use experienced .net developers(less SP knowledge) to work with SharePoint and get the job done.

Comment: JonH - not a bad idea at all. I think that I will approach this project using this strategy. Thank you.